# Find out the cases having discrepancies

Tags: vba, excel

I am having a sheet having seven cloumns. First six  columns having either true or false and in last column I have to mention the heading of false cases in one statement. Below is the excel.
[Excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPUrd.png)

I have tried if else statement but there are too many possibilities. Since I am new to VBA i don't know any shortcut to that.Any suggestions?.... Thanks

Comment: You should show your effort: what code have you tried?

Comment: `Select case...` statement, or `if...elseif...elseif...else...end if` - you can make use of these, combined with a loop. But you might be better off with a formula, if you odn't know VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this simple vba code,

```
Sub TEXTJOIN()
Dim i As Long, str As String, k As Long, j As Long
str = ""
j = 0
For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A" & i & ":F" & i), True) = 6 Then
    Cells(i, 7) = "No Discrepancy Found"
Else
    For k = 1 To 6
        If Cells(i, k) = False Then
            str = str & Cells(1, k) & ","
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next k
    str = Left(str, Len(str) - 1) & " mismatch found"
    Cells(i, 7) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(str, ",", " and ", j - 1)
    str = ""
    j = 0
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou @Gowtham Shiva... I am new to VBA..still in learning phase...Thanks :)

Comment: @KirtiPal Please mark the answer as correct to make the question resolved. You can do that by clicking the tick mark near the answer

Comment: I understood the logic but can we do the same for varying columns..like if these 6 columns keep on changing there place like instead of A to F sometimes they are present from F to K...

Comment: Actually the sheets I am working upon are having varying columns sometimes.... can you plz suggest me for that @gowtham shiva

Comment: @KirtiPal you should be changing that in the code based on your columns. especially in the `Countif` function and the for loop for `k`

Comment: I want to write a single code which will search the first data which is "Name" here and will start check the next columns also and then give discrepancies. For finding first column I have used:Cells.Find(What:="Name", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Activate

Comment: @KirtiPal you are in the right direction. From there you can loop the K variable

Answer (score 0):

Here's simple code which you should try:

```
Sub FindDiscrepancies()
Dim lastRow, i, j As Long
Dim discrepancies As String: discrepancies = ""
'find number of last row
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastRow
    For j = 1 To 6
        If LCase(Cells(i, j).Value) = "false" Then
            discrepancies = discrepancies & Cells(1, j).Value & ", "
        End If
    Next j
    If discrepancies = "" Then
        Cells(i, 7).Value = "No discrepancies found"
    Else
        Cells(i, 7).Value = "Mismatch found in " & discrepancies
    End If
    discrepancies = ""
Next i

End Sub
```